# Multicols package creating new column at the bottom of page instead of top

Tags: formatting, multicol

When the code featured below is compiled, the result is a page in which the second column begins near the bottom of the page instead of near the top. Using overleaf to compile code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{\bf{MENU}}
\author{}
\date{}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[
top    = 1cm,
bottom = 0.5cm,
left   = 3.00cm,
right  = 2.50cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\hline
\begin{multicols}{2}
[
\section*{Appetizers}
\normalsize{Jalape\~{n}o Poppers} \hspace{11.5mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent6 count served with ranch}
\newline
\normalsize{Mozzarella Sticks} \hspace{12mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent6 count served with marinara}
\newline
\normalsize{Fried Ravioli}\hspace{19.9mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent6 count served with marinara}
\newline
\normalsize{Onion Rings}\hspace{20.6mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent10 count served with house sauce}
\newline
\normalsize{JoJo Fries} \hspace{16mm} 4.99 S/5.99 L
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent served with ketchup}
\newline
\normalsize{Garlic Toast}\hspace{20.6mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent served with marinara}
\newline
\normalsize{Garlic Toast w/ Cheese}\hspace{3.5mm} 6.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent served with marinara}
\newline
\normalsize{Garlic Bread Sticks}\hspace{10mm} 6.77
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent8 count served with ranch}
\newline
\normalsize{Cheesy Bread}\hspace{18.85mm} 6.77
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent16 count served with marinara}
\newline
\normalsize{Chicken Strips} \hspace{16.5mm} 5.67
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent6 count served with honey mustard}
\newline
\normalsize{Breaded Mushrooms} \hspace{7.21mm} 4.55
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent16 count served with ranch}
\newline
\normalsize{Fried Calamari} \hspace{16mm} 2.44
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent served with house spicy marinara}
\section*{Pizzas}
\subsection*{Specialty}
\normalsize{Supreme} \hspace{12mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Pepperoni, Sausage, Onion, Green Pepper, Mushroom}
\newline
\normalsize{White Gourmet}\hspace{19.9mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Garlic Sauce, Chicken, Red Pepper, Tomato, Onion}
\newline
\normalsize{Mega Meat}\hspace{20.6mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Pepperoni, Sausage, Ham, Bacon, Ground Beef}
\newline
\normalsize{Veggie} \hspace{16mm} 4.99 S/5.99 L
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Onion, Green Pepper, Tomato, Olives, Mushroom}
\newline
\normalsize{BBQ Chicken}\hspace{20.6mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent BBQ Sauce, Chicken, Bacon, Onion}
\newline
\normalsize{Buffalo Chicken}\hspace{3.5mm} 6.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Buffalo Sauce, Chicken, Onion}
\newline
\normalsize{Hawaiian} \hspace{12mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Ham, Bacon, Pineapple}
\newline
\normalsize{The Works}\hspace{19.9mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Pepperoni, Sausage, Onion, Green Pepper, Mushroom,
\newline
\indent
Ham, Olives, Ground Beef}
\newline
\normalsize{Margherita}\hspace{20.6mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Fresh Mozzarella Cheese, Sliced Tomato, Basil, Parmesean}
\newline
\normalsize{Alfredo} \hspace{16mm} 4.99 S/5.99 L
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Alfredo Sauce, Spinach, Broccoli, Chicken}
\newline
\normalsize{Steak}\hspace{20.6mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Garlic Sauce, Steak, Onion, Green Pepper, Mushroom}
\newline
\normalsize{Seafood}\hspace{3.5mm} 6.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent House-made Lobster Sauce, Crab, Shrimp, Spinach}
\newline
\normalsize{Artichoke}\hspace{20.6mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Pesto Sauce, Artichoke, Onion, Tomato, Red Pepper}
]
\newline
\subsection*{Create Your Own}
this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample
\end{multicols}{2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: font sizes do not take an argument `\footnotesize{\indent6 count served with ranch}` is  `\footnotesize\indent6 count served with ranch` and makes the rest of the documnent ha size not just `6 count served with ranch` (also `\bf` has not been defined by default in latex since 1993)

Comment: did you intend to put the entire menu in the optional `[...]` argument so spanning the columns?

Comment: your example produces the error `! Misplaced \noalign.` (so essentially no ouput, any pdf made if you scroll past an error is not inended to be usable, just a debugging aid)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps that this is what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{\bf{MENU}}
\author{}
\date{}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[
top    = 1cm,
bottom = 0.5cm,
left   = 3.00cm,
right  = 2.50cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
%\hline
\begin{multicols}{2}
[\section*{Appetizers}]
\normalsize{Jalape\~{n}o Poppers} \hspace{11.5mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent6 count served with ranch}
\newline
\normalsize{Mozzarella Sticks} \hspace{12mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent6 count served with marinara}
\newline
\normalsize{Fried Ravioli}\hspace{19.9mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent6 count served with marinara}
\newline
\normalsize{Onion Rings}\hspace{20.6mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent10 count served with house sauce}
\newline
\normalsize{JoJo Fries} \hspace{16mm} 4.99 S/5.99 L
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent served with ketchup}
\newline
\normalsize{Garlic Toast}\hspace{20.6mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent served with marinara}
\newline
\normalsize{Garlic Toast w/ Cheese}\hspace{3.5mm} 6.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent served with marinara}
\newline
\normalsize{Garlic Bread Sticks}\hspace{10mm} 6.77
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent8 count served with ranch}
\newline
\normalsize{Cheesy Bread}\hspace{18.85mm} 6.77
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent16 count served with marinara}
\newline
\normalsize{Chicken Strips} \hspace{16.5mm} 5.67
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent6 count served with honey mustard}
\newline
\normalsize{Breaded Mushrooms} \hspace{7.21mm} 4.55
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent16 count served with ranch}
\newline
\normalsize{Fried Calamari} \hspace{16mm} 2.44
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent served with house spicy marinara}
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{Pizzas}\subsection*{Specialty}]
\normalsize{Supreme} \hspace{12mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Pepperoni, Sausage, Onion, Green Pepper, Mushroom}
\newline
\normalsize{White Gourmet}\hspace{19.9mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Garlic Sauce, Chicken, Red Pepper, Tomato, Onion}
\newline
\normalsize{Mega Meat}\hspace{20.6mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Pepperoni, Sausage, Ham, Bacon, Ground Beef}
\newline
\normalsize{Veggie} \hspace{16mm} 4.99 S/5.99 L
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Onion, Green Pepper, Tomato, Olives, Mushroom}
\newline
\normalsize{BBQ Chicken}\hspace{20.6mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent BBQ Sauce, Chicken, Bacon, Onion}
\newline
\normalsize{Buffalo Chicken}\hspace{3.5mm} 6.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Buffalo Sauce, Chicken, Onion}
\newline
\normalsize{Hawaiian} \hspace{12mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Ham, Bacon, Pineapple}
\newline
\normalsize{The Works}\hspace{19.9mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Pepperoni, Sausage, Onion, Green Pepper, Mushroom,
\newline
\indent
Ham, Olives, Ground Beef}
\newline
\normalsize{Margherita}\hspace{20.6mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Fresh Mozzarella Cheese, Sliced Tomato, Basil, Parmesean}
\newline
\normalsize{Alfredo} \hspace{16mm} 4.99 S/5.99 L
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Alfredo Sauce, Spinach, Broccoli, Chicken}
\newline
\normalsize{Steak}\hspace{20.6mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Garlic Sauce, Steak, Onion, Green Pepper, Mushroom}
\newline
\normalsize{Seafood}\hspace{3.5mm} 6.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent House-made Lobster Sauce, Crab, Shrimp, Spinach}
\newline
\normalsize{Artichoke}\hspace{20.6mm} 4.99
\newline
\footnotesize{\indent Pesto Sauce, Artichoke, Onion, Tomato, Red Pepper}
]
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\subsection*{Create Your Own}]
this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample this is sample
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The output will be this:

[image]

Comment: This is still demonstrating the misleading usage `\normalsize{Mozzarella Sticks}`

Answer (score 1):

You may liked:

[image]

For the shorter code is defined new command in which are collected style for each dish group:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vmargin={1cm,0.5cm},
            hmargin={3.00cm,2.50cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{13mm}
\newcommand\DN[3]{\noindent{\bfseries   % <---
                  #1 \hfill #2}\par
                  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-5em}{\raggedright\small 
                  #3}
                  \medskip\par} % Dish Description

\title{\textbf{MENU}}
\author{}
\date{}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{2}
[
\section*{Appetizers}
]
\DN{Jalape\~{n}o Poppers}{4.99}
{6 count served with ranch}
%
\DN{Mozzarella Sticks}{4.99}
{6 count served with marinara}
%
\DN{Fried Ravioli}{4.99}
{6 count served with marinara}
%
\DN{Onion Rings}{4.99}
{10 count served with house sauce}
%
\DN{JoJo Fries}{4.99 S/5.99 L}
{served with ketchup}
%
\DN{Garlic Toast}{4.99}
{served with marinara}
%
\DN{Garlic Toast w/ Cheese}{6.99}
{served with marinara}
%
\DN{Garlic Bread Sticks}{6.77}
{8 count served with ranch}
%
\DN{Cheesy Bread}{6.77}
{16 count served with marinara}
%
\DN{Chicken Strips}{5.67}
{count served with honey mustard}
%
\DN{Breaded Mushrooms}{4.55}
{16 count served with ranch}
%
\DN{Fried Calamari}{2.44}
{served with house spicy marinara}
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}
[\section*{Pizzas}
 \subsection*{Specialty}]
%
\DN{Supreme}{4.99}
{Pepperoni, Sausage, Onion, Green Pepper, Mushroom}
%
\DN{White Gourmet}{4.99}
{Garlic Sauce, Chicken, Red Pepper, Tomato, Onion}
%
\DN{Mega Meat}{4.99}
{\indent Pepperoni, Sausage, Ham, Bacon, Ground Beef}
%
\DN{Veggie}{4.99 S/5.99 L}
{Onion, Green Pepper, Tomato, Olives, Mushroom}
%
\DN{BBQ Chicken}{4.99}
{BBQ Sauce, Chicken, Bacon, Onion}
%
\DN{Buffalo Chicken}{6.99}
{Buffalo Sauce, Chicken, Onion}
%\columnbreak
\DN{Hawaiian}{4.99}
{Ham, Bacon, Pineapple}
%
\DN{The Works}{4.99}
{Pepperoni, Sausage, Onion, Green Pepper, Mushroom,
    Ham, Olives, Ground Beef}
%
\DN{Margherita}{4.99}
{\indent Fresh Mozzarella Cheese, Sliced Tomato, Basil, Parmesean}
%
\DN{Alfredo}{4.99 S/5.99 L}
{\indent Alfredo Sauce, Spinach, Broccoli, Chicken}
%
\DN{Steak}{4.99}
{Garlic Sauce, Steak, Onion, Green Pepper, Mushroom}
%
\DN{Seafood}{6.99}
{House-made Lobster Sauce, Crab, Shrimp, Spinach}
%
\DN{Artichoke}{4.99}
{Pesto Sauce, Artichoke, Onion, Tomato, Red Pepper}
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}
[
\subsection*{Create Your Own}
]
\DN{this is sample}{1.11}
{this is sample this}
%
\DN{this is sample}{1.11}
{this is sample this}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```